# App crash when re-opened (ImmutableMap)

Tags: android, dictionary, android-activity, lifecycle

Sorry for my bad English.
In my app I'm using ImmutableMap from Guava library to store some keys and values. 
When I press home button and then re-open app it crashes and logcat says that there are duplicate values in map.
That's because I fill the map on MainActivity start.
Is it possible somehow to find out, if MainActivity already exists and not to fill it?

**One Solution**: The only workaround I see is to check the size of the map, and if it's null, then fill it.

**EDIT:** The duplicate values appear, because map is filled on first launch, and then, after activity restart, it tries to fill them again, causoing error. 
Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.main);         
        Map.map_fill();
....
}
```

LogCat:

```
01-11 01:56:31.970: D/AndroidRuntime(30500): Shutting down VM
01-11 01:56:31.970: W/dalvikvm(30500): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41864ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(30500): Process: ru.mastergroosha.idneval2, PID: 30500
E/AndroidRuntime(30500): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.mastergroosha.idneval2/ru.mastergroosha.idneval2.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 01=Веригин Вадим Сергеевич and 01=Веригин Вадим Сергеевич
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2248)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key: 01=Веригин Вадим Сергеевич and 01=Веригин Вадим Сергеевич
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.checkNoConflict(ImmutableMap.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at com.google.common.collect.RegularImmutableBiMap.<init>(RegularImmutableBiMap.java:77)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at com.google.common.collect.ImmutableBiMap$Builder.build(ImmutableBiMap.java:172)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at ru.mastergroosha.idneval2.Map.make_names_array(Map.java:77)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at ru.mastergroosha.idneval2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:114)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5241)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
E/AndroidRuntime(30500):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat

Comment: Did you implement both onStart and onResume?

Comment: No, I didn't, should I?

Comment: post your main activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your Map is a static map.
So every time  that you enter into the `onCreate(...)` callback there is an attempt fill you map that cannot be modified.

If you check the [documentation of Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) there are several reason why the onCreate(...) is called.

A better solution would be having your map declared into an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object that would allow you to do the initialization of your map.

1. Provide a getter for your Map in the just created class
2. Reference the Application into your `AndroidManifest.xml`
3. In your Activity get the Application and safely cast it to `YourApplication.class`